# Is Shapeless' type inequality buggy?

Tags: scala, shapeless

Type inequality in shapeless does not seem to be safe once type parameters enter the picture.

For example the following code compiles

```
def someMethod[T](in : T) = {

  implicitly[T =:!= String]

  // some operation that requires T not String could be called here
  // even though there is no guarantee that this is safe
}

val a = someMethod("abc") // here we have just proven String != String
```

My intuition is that the correct behavior should be a compile time error (we have generated a proof that `String =!:= String`)

This is not related to the `=:!=` operator but to all situations in which implicit conflicts are used to emulate a negation operator.

Is this really a bug or am I missing an important point?

Comment: Would you mind creating an issue for this on the shapeless issue tracker so that this doesn't get forgotten about?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug, or at best a surprising misfeature.

Answer (score 1):

`T =:!= String` needs to be an implicit argument of `someMethod`. We need to collect the evidence that `T` is not a `String` at the call site, otherwise it's too late. `T` is erased within the body of `someMethod`.

```
def someMethod[T](in : T)(implicit ev: T =:!= String) = {
  println("Definitely not a string")
}

scala> someMethod("abc")
<console>:16: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method neqAmbig1 in package shapeless of type [A]=> shapeless.=:!=[A,A]
 and method neqAmbig2 in package shapeless of type [A]=> shapeless.=:!=[A,A]
 match expected type shapeless.=:!=[String,String]
       someMethod("abc")
                 ^
```

Comment: I understand what you say, but the problem is that people who write the code on the app side of things tend to forget implicits with probability one... Can you help me understand why my example compiles? You say erasure plays a role but I don't quite understand why it allows the compiler to generate the implicit in my example, is the erasure of `F` effectively turning it into `Any` at some point?

Comment: @luca The problem is that this trick works by providing implicit evidence that another implicit was not found. In other cases when you try to prove something about some unbounded T <: Any the compiler will complain that he can't find the implicit evidence. But in this case the fact that he does not find the evidence that T =:= String (because he knows nothing about T) will cause the evidence that T =:!= String to be found, even though nothing is known about T.